# UILabel Not Showing On Static TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, label

Hello I'm having a little bit of trouble with something I'm working on. I have a static TableView with sections and I'm trying to get my text to be positioned in a certain spot so I have a ui label linked to a uitableviewcell. But for some reason It's not working. If you have any ideas on why I'm having trouble with this that would be great. I'm also a bit new to iOS development, just putting that out there.

TableViewController.m:

```
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    int row = [indexPath row];

    if (indexPath.section==0)
        cell.textLabel.text = _1[row];
    if (indexPath.section==1)
        cell.textLabel.text = _2[row];
    if (indexPath.section==2)
        cell.textLabel.text = _3[row];
    if (indexPath.section==3)
        cell.textLabel.text = _4[row];
    if (indexPath.section==4)
        cell.textLabel.text = _5[row];
    if (indexPath.section==5)
        cell.textLabel.text = _6[row];
    if (indexPath.section==6)
        cell.textLabel.text = _7[row];
    if (indexPath.section==7)
        cell.textLabel.text = _8[row];
    return cell;
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

TableCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@end
```

Comment: Check out iboutlet connected to tableviewcell. and in code replace textLabel with TitleLabel.

Comment: Changed the code and the tableviewcell is connected to the cell on the storyboard, and the label is linked to the iboutlet. It's still not working.

Comment: Did you set the class name in Identity inspector as TableCell in Custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
cell.textLabel.text = _1[row];
```

with

```
cell.TitleLabel.text = _1[row];
```

this line is not needed anymore

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

in case TableCell is with xib, then you need to load it.

```
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.TitleLabel.text = _1[row];

return cell;
```

you should check this

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

method to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically. if you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry (Apple Document)

in your viewDidLoad method

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[TableCell class]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Thats what I used originally but It just shows a blank cell :(

Comment: because you are allocting [[TableCell alloc] it . it will return you a new cell . you do not need it any more. this TableCell, you have in storyboard or with xib

Comment: After I removed it the application just crashes.

Comment: check these link for custom cell, [link1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) [link2](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/)

Comment: crash meaning- cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning a nil value and then configureCellForDisplay is expecting a UITableViewCell. The storyboard or XIB does not have a cell defined with the cell identifier you specified. Better check the spelling of identifier.

Comment: i think , you have  a class for TableCell with xib (based on this line). its a different case. you need to load the nib file. check the edited answer

Comment: I'm not using xib interfaces just a storyboard.